# How is systemd "offline-updates" configured on a Debian server?

Tags: debian, systemd

How is systemd "offline-updates" configured on a Debian server?

Debian 9 with Gnome seems to come configured with systemd's "offline-updates" feature already configured. Is there a package I can install on a server system to get the same behaviour?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

On Debian servers, instead of relying on a minimal environment after a reboot to install package upgrades, we tend to recommend upgrading while the system is live and restarting when necessary.

This is supported by a number of packages:

- `apt` itself includes systemd timers (and a cron job so it will work without systemd) implementing periodic index refreshes (`APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists`, set to 0 by default and thus disabled) and automatic package downloads (`APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages`, also set to 0 by default);
- [`unattended-upgrades`](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) implements automatic upgrades of packages which can be upgraded safely (typically, security updates); it hooks in to the timers provided by `apt` (`APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade`, also set to 0 by default);
- `needrestart` detects daemons which need restarting, and restarts them with the appropriate systemd context (if systemd is in use); it also supports rebooting if necessary following a kernel upgrade.

There are pros and cons to both approaches. Rebooting for all upgrades ensures that obsolete processes aren’t ever available, and minimises the risk of package database corruption (especially in the RPM world); obviously it reduces uptime, but in a world of load-balanced, highly-available *services* rather than *servers*, that doesn’t necessarily matter much. Upgrading a live system minimises the risk of ending up with an unreachable server, and keeps the system services available (although `apt` could be improved in this regard too, since daemons can be stopped for a long time during upgrades — but that’s another issue); it does however leave you vulnerable for slightly longer once a security hole has been found.

The [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.offline-updates.7.en.html) you linked to details the requirements for anyone wanting to implement a server-oriented upgrade system; it would be relatively straightforward to do so on Debian, but as far as I know there is no packaged implementation. You could build on top of the framework described above, with the automatic downloads as they’re done now, and `unattended-upgrades` running in the minimal upgrade environment...